# NSInvalidArgumentException, Unrec thrown in Monotouch

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios

The issue I am facing is thrown on only one device out of several test devices. All devices are iPhone 4s iOS 5.1.1 with another with iOS 6.0.1.

There are several answers to similar questions but none contain both symptoms.

The application has been written in Monotouch.

The symptoms of the issue are

The application will not change orientation on the affected device.
An NSInvalidArgumentException is thrown when accessing certain views on the affected device.

The full exception is:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UITableViewCell updateConstraintsIfNeeded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e07540
```

The Stack Trace is

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UITableViewCell updateConstraintsIfNeeded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c3cc20
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded () [0x00010] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIView.g.cs:1626
  at XXXXXX.IOS.Dialogs.NewStyledMultilineElement.GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tv) [0x0000f] in /Users/gavin/Perforce/Jon_PI-151_9051/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/v1.3.1/Mobile/XXXXXX/IOS/XXXXXX.Dialogs/My Work/WorkDetailDialogController.cs:30
  at MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController+Source.GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00029] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/MonoTouch.Dialog/MonoTouch.Dialog/DialogViewController.cs:340
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at XXXXXX.IOS.Application.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/gavin/Perforce/Jon_PI-151_9051/Pall/XXXXXX/v1.3.1/Mobile/XXXXXX/IOS/XXXXXX.Application/Main.cs:28
```

The code that is causing the exception is

```
public class NewStyledMultilineElement : StyledMultilineElement
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
            UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(tv);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            cell.UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded();
            return cell;
    }

    public NewStyledMultilineElement(string caption, string value) :base(caption,value)
    {
    }
}
```

The line that is throwing the error is 
cell.UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded();

The version information is

MonoDevelop 3.0.5
Runtime
  Mono 2.10.9
  GTK 2.24.10
XCode 4.5.1
Monotouch 6.0.6

The settings on the affected device have been compaired to other devices that function as expected, with no obvious differences.

It is possible that the symptoms are for different issues. However, this is the only acception that is thrown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Further investigation has resolved the issue, temporarily. However the root cause has not been confirmed. The solutions are as follows

To resolve the orientation symptom, the following code was added to the base view controller from which all view controllers are dervied.

`public override bool ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        return true;
    }`

To resolve the NSInvalidArgumentException, StyledMultilineElement have been used instead of the derived class. This issue could be being caused by the GC, but varification of that would be appreciated.

The solutions solve the issue, without identifying the root causes. Any explination of why this is happening on only one device and not all would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a feature of iOS6, which is constraint based layout. This is not available on iOS5. Hence, calling `UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded()` will fail an all devices running on iOS5.x and older.

See Apple's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/updateConstraints

> updateConstraintsIfNeeded Updates the constraints for the receiving
>   view and its subviews.
>
> > - (void)updateConstraintsIfNeeded Discussion Whenever a new layout pass is triggered for a view, the system invokes this method to ensure
> >       that any constraints for the view and its subviews are updated with
> >       information from the current view hierarchy and its constraints. This
> >       method is called automatically by the system, but may be invoked
> >       manually if you need to examine the most up to date constraints.
> >
> > Subclasses should not override this method.
> >
> > ***Availability Available in iOS 6.0 and later***. Declared In UIView.h

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I can not accept it as an answer as out of the 8 test devices I have all are iOS 5.1.1 apart from 1 that is iOS 6.0.1. The application only fails on 1 device that runs 5.1.1.

Comment: You are using an iOS6 method. There's nothing to discuss about it. Maybe it has been in iOS5 already but maybe it is incomplete/broken. But for sure: it was not intended for public use. Are you using a constrained layout? If not: just remove the call. It's not required.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have removed the problem code and it did fix the issue. I was not aware that the method could have been a private API or not completly implemented. However, this does not explain why only the one device reacted to the code with an error whilst other devices using the same OS function as required. This is the issue that I am anxious to resolve, as it may impact on the number of hours required for deployment testing. Once again thank you.